# Can you freeze the App until a (asynchronous) event has occured?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to show an `AdMobInterstitial`-Ad in my App before pushing to the next screen.

For now, I am using this method:

1. show the Ad (which takes 1-2 seconds to load)
2. pushing to the next screen

```
onpress={ () =>{
    (title.slice(0, 4) === "X-01"
              ? navigation.push(...)
              : navigation.push(...));
    showAsyncAD();
}
}
```

The ad loads asynchroniously so the app pushes to the next screen, then shows the ad.
I want it to first load the ad then push to the next screen.

I tried this:

```
onpress={() =>
showAsyncAD().then(
() => title.slice(0, 4) === "X-01"
              ? navigation.push(...)
              : navigation.push(...)
                   );
}
}
```

This does indeed work **but** until the ad comes up the user can press buttons which he is not allowed to. He can actually just press the button again and get to the screen before the ad starts to play.

How can I freeze the App until the ad comes up so the user wont do anything he is not allowed to?

If a loading circle is possible with this it would be the best option!

Thanks for any inputs!!!

EDIT: I want to make **the whole App to freeze** until the ad is shown

Comment: Which button exactly are we talking about? You tagged this with react-native, so I assume the button is on screen in the form of just a basic `<Button ... />`? Because in that case you can easily control what happens and doesn't happen when the button is clicked/tapped.

Comment: I don't know the context in which your function is executed. Normally you would conditionally render a loading component until some state updated and rerenders the component in which your had has been rendered before.

Comment: I call the function in an onpress() method. I dont only want to freeze the button; I want to freeze the whole app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state value which shows async action processing

```js
const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false);
```

```js
setProcessing(true)
showAsyncAD().then(
  () => {
    setProcessing(false)
    title.slice(0, 4) === "X-01"
                ? navigation.push(...)
                : navigation.push(...)
  })
```

And disable button(s) that you don't want to be clicked while async action is performed. for example;

```html
<TouchableOpacity disabled={processing}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to disable the whole screen, you can show a transparent overlay `View` on the screen. It will have the full width and height of the screen.

```
return (
  <View style={{
    position: 'relative',
    ...
  }}>
    // your views here
    {processing && <View style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }} />}
  </View>
)
```

Comment: But this only deactivates the button. I want to deactivate the the whole app temporarily.

Comment: This looks promising. Where exactly do I have to write this? Or in which view. But thanks already!

Comment: You can place the overlay view right inside of the container view. Please check the updated code. Hope it could make sense.

Comment: The Problem is that it dont cover the navigators even though it's `absolute` and full width and hide